# Angular 4 , 'this' is undefined when using callback 'onComponentInitFunction' function of ng2-smart table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I am using ng2-smart-table in my component.

I am trying to invoke the parent component's **approveTheOrder()** method but I am unable to get the object of the parent class

Below is the snippet

```
{
  title: "Actions",
  type: "custom",
  renderComponent: ActionRenderComponent,
  onComponentInitFunction(instance) {
    instance.actionEmitter.subscribe(row => {
      if(row == CONSTANT.STATUS_APPROVE){
        //here 'row' value is from childComponent-ActionRenderComponent,which I am able to get easily in parentComponet 
       this.approveTheOrder(instance.rowData.id); // here this is undefined, 

      }
      if(row == CONSTANT.STATUS_REJECT){
        this.rejectOrder();//this is undefined
      }
      if(row == CONSTANT.STATUS_PENDING){
        this.pendingOrder(); // this is undefined
      }
    });
  },

  filter: false
};
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get the 'this' in the below onComponentInitFunction() ?

Below is the image of the error that I am getting.[image]

Also I tried to use 'bind' function was unsuccessful in achieving the goal, Could anyone please guide me here, I am really stuck at this point.

**EDIT 1**
Note that I am able to get event from **ChildComponent** in the **parentComponent**, but the problem here is specific to ng2-smart-table component.

To get the value from **ChildComponent**, I am trying to use in-build callback function **onComponentInitFunction(instance)** of ng2-smart-table component

Comment: @Yurzui - Yes your given solution worked for me. Please feel free to answer the question so that no one else gets stuck with this problem

Comment: @Z.Bagley - This problem is specific to ng-smart-table, I am able to get back the value from the ChildComponent into the ParentComponent's contructor. But the problem arisis in the onComponentInitFunction() function.

Comment: Apologies, misunderstood and removed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following syntax:

```typescript
{
  onComponentInitFunction(instance) {
    ...
```

will be transformed to function expression:

```typescript
{
  onComponentInitFunction: function(instance) {
    ...
```

You should use arrow function to retain `this`:

```typescript
onComponentInitFunction: (instance) => {
```