# How to invoke method from filterFunction() in ng2-smart-table?

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I am trying to invoke a method from a filterfunction() by using 'this' keyword. However, I realize that 'this' refers to the event handler instead the component, and the value I get for 'this' is null so I get a runtime error.

```
export class SmartTableComponent {

  settings = {
    ...
    columns: {
      ...
      firstName: {
        title: 'First Name',
        type: 'string',
        filterFunction(cell?: any, search?: string): boolean {          
          return this.doFilter(cell, search);
        }
      },
      ...
    },
    ...
  };


  doFilter(cell?: any, search?: string): boolean{
    return true;
  }
}
```

In Java, we would get a reference to 'this' by using SmartTableComponent.this.doFilter(...) but this does not seems to work in TypeScript.

How can I invoke a component's method from a filterFunction in ng2-smart-table?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that, by using a lambda expression instead of an anonymous function, the value of 'this' is maintained from the wrapper class. So, this is the solution:

```
export class SmartTableComponent {

  settings = {
    ...
    columns: {
      ...
      firstName: {
        title: 'First Name',
        type: 'string',
        filterFunction:(cell?: any, search?: string) => {
          return this.filterByText(cell.doc[0]['value'], search);
        },
      },
      ...
    },
    ...
  };


  doFilter(cell?: any, search?: string): boolean{
    return true;
  }
}
```

I got the idea here: [Angular 4 , 'this' is undefined when using callback 'onComponentInitFunction' function of ng2-smart table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613256/angular-4-this-is-undefined-when-using-callback-oncomponentinitfunction-fu?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that whoever invokes this function will set the *this* variable, and so your idea of what *this* means in the function has changed. To fix the *this* to the function (and prevent it from changing), you can use [Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). The following code shows the (hopefully) working example.

```
export class SmartTableComponent {

  settings = {
    ...
    columns: {
      ...
      firstName: {
        title: 'First Name',
        type: 'string',
        filterFunction(cell?: any, search?: string): boolean {          
          return this.doFilter(cell, search);
        }.bind(this)
      },
      ...
    },
    ...
  };


  doFilter(cell?: any, search?: string): boolean{
    return true;
  }
}
```

My previous explanation is more intuitive than strictly correct, if you really want to know how it works, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: .bind(this) does not seem to compiler in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Use filterFunction like below

```
    ...
    filterFunction: (cell?: any, search?: string): boolean => {          
              return this.doFilter(cell, search);
    }
    ...
```